# Filtering by renamed column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
IFNULL(CHAR_LENGTH(fiedl1), 0) +
IFNULL(CHAR_LENGTH(fiedl2), 0) +
IFNULL(CHAR_LENGTH(fiedl3), 0) +
IFNULL(CHAR_LENGTH(fiedl4), 0) +
IFNULL(CHAR_LENGTH(fiedl5), 0) +
IFNULL(CHAR_LENGTH(fiedl6), 0) AS L
FROM mytable;
```

I only want the records that L are smaller than 100. If I use WHERE clause then I get "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'L' in 'where clause'"

Comment: You cannot use the alias in your where clause. To understand why this is please give this article a read: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a derived table:

```
SELECT L FROM 
(
    SELECT  
    IFNULL(CHAR_LENGTH(fiedl1), 0) + 
    IFNULL(CHAR_LENGTH(fiedl2), 0) + 
    IFNULL(CHAR_LENGTH(fiedl3), 0) + 
    IFNULL(CHAR_LENGTH(fiedl4), 0) + 
    IFNULL(CHAR_LENGTH(fiedl5), 0) + 
    IFNULL(CHAR_LENGTH(fiedl6), 0) AS L 
    FROM mytable
)  AS R
WHERE L < 100;
```

Comment: This way is perfect to my second condition. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT 
IFNULL(CHAR_LENGTH(fiedl1), 0) +
IFNULL(CHAR_LENGTH(fiedl2), 0) +
IFNULL(CHAR_LENGTH(fiedl3), 0) +
IFNULL(CHAR_LENGTH(fiedl4), 0) +
IFNULL(CHAR_LENGTH(fiedl5), 0) +
IFNULL(CHAR_LENGTH(fiedl6), 0) AS L
FROM mytable
WHERE field1 = "yes"
HAVING L < 100;
```

Comment: Can you do this without an aggregate function and a `group by`?

Comment: I believe so... I didnt test but I dont see why not. HAVING is similar to a WHERE except it is evaluated after all data has been selected out. Anything available in the SELECT part is available for use in the HAVING clause.

Comment: I want another OR condition as well: `field9 = "yes"`.

Comment: @Abe, you are correct! However, it seems some RDBMS's deviate from standard SQL in this area. For example, MySQL supports HAVING conditions with anything in the SELECT clause.

Comment: @Brad, I can't put WHERE clause for another OR condition and I can't put in HAVING clause because `field9` is not in SELECT clause.

Comment: @Brad, `fiedl9`! Note that it's not in SELECT clause.